# Keras custom generator: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (256, 1)

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-preprocessing

I have a large dataset (30 000 images, 80kB each), and I'm trying to load it into my model in batches in order to not run of out memory on my GPU. My single *image* is a 200x200 numpy array, with values either 1 or 0, stored in csv file. So I don't need to resize it or use any image reader as it's already an array. I'm using a custom generator to achieve this:

```
class My_Custom_Generator(keras.utils.Sequence):
  
  def __init__(self, image_filenames, labels, batch_size):
    self.image_filenames = image_filenames
    self.labels = labels
    self.batch_size = batch_size
  
  def __len__(self):
    return (np.ceil(len(self.image_filenames) / float(self.batch_size))).astype(np.int)
  
  def __getitem__(self, idx):
    batch_x = self.image_filenames[idx * self.batch_size: (idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
    batch_y = self.labels[idx * self.batch_size: (idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
    
    return np.array(batch_x), np.array(batch_y)
```

My model looks like this:

```
X_train_filenames = np.load('X_train_filenames.npy')
y_train = np.load('y_train.npy')
X_val_filenames = np.load('X_val_filenames.npy')
y_val = np.load('y_val.npy')


batch_size = 256
my_training_batch_generator = My_Custom_Generator(X_train_filenames, y_train, batch_size)
my_validation_batch_generator = My_Custom_Generator(X_val_filenames, y_val, batch_size)


model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (3,3),input_shape=(200,200,1)))
#model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Dropout(0.15))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(32))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))


model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

model.fit_generator(generator=my_training_batch_generator,
                   steps_per_epoch = int(y_train.shape[0] // batch_size),
                   epochs = 10,
                   verbose = 1,
                   validation_data = my_validation_batch_generator,
                   validation_steps = int(y_val.shape[0] // batch_size))
```

I get an error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (256, 1)
```

In my understanding the input should be a 4 dimensional array of shape `(None,200,200,1)`, but I don't know how to achieve it, since I just started learning how to load a dataset in parts and not all at once.

Comment: you're passing a string into a CNN

Comment: @NicolasGervais Could you please elaborate? If I was passing a string, I think the error would be rather different.

Comment: try something like `next(iter(my_training_batch_generator))` to inspect the batches. if you're not passing strings, why is your dataset called `X_train_filenames`?

Comment: You're right. After ```next(iter...``` I got an array ```(... 'qtc_h3887.csv', 'qtc_h6186.csv'], dtype='<U14'), array([[0., 1.],
       [1., 0.],
       [0., 1.] ...)```. I was basing my code on this article: https://medium.com/@mrgarg.rajat/training-on-large-datasets-that-dont-fit-in-memory-in-keras-60a974785d71 (apparently without full understanding) with the minor difference, that I used csvs instead of pngs.

Comment: How can I correct it though? Should I just change my dataset to contain actuall files and not just their names?

Comment: Yes, a CNN needs numeric input

Comment: But then I will have a 2GB file containing all my data. I was trying to avoid that and load the files separately from the directory.